# Show function $f(x,y)=(x^2-y^2,2xy)$ is $1$-$1$ by Inverse Function Theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions, inverse-function-theorem

I'm trying to prove the problem below - which comes from Munkres' "Analysis on Manifolds" book in the section on the Inverse function theorem.

Since its in the chapter on the Inverse Function Theorem I figured I'd start by showing that $f$ satisfies the conditions of the theorem.  Writing the Jacobian shows that it's both $C^r$ and we get $\det f'(x,y)=4x^2+4y^2\neq0$ when $x>0$.  So we can apply the theorem but I'm unsure of how to proceed to show that $f$ is $1$-$1$.  And I didn't see how to use the hint they provided.

Thanks!
[image]

> Let $f\colon \mathbf R^2\to \mathbf R^2$ be defined by the equation
>   $$f(x,y)=(x^2-y^2,2xy).$$
>   (a) Show that $f$ is one-to-one on the set of all $(x,y)$ with $x>0$. [Hint: If $f(x,y)=f(a,b)$, then $\|f(x,y)\|=\|f(a,b)\|$.]

Comment: It is straightforward to compute an explicit inverse, but an answer based on the hint is not leaping out at me.

Comment: @Holo It would be great if you wrote that up as an answer

Comment: @Holo Also, I find that it's more convenient to write `$x^2$` than `$x²$`, as you did in your comment.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I posted it as answer. Also, normally write x^2 but right now I'm in bed with my phone, so the autocorrect change my x to X all the time if I use ^.

Comment: @Holo ah, fancy.

Comment: @Holo Thanks for using your phone to help me out instead of watching world cup highlights!

Comment: @johnfowles don't mind that, sport was never my interest. I would have used the computer instead but my laziness took over and I don't want to get up( we all have those days)

Comment: Note the connection with the complex function $f(z)=z^2$.

Comment: [Using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24f(x%2Cy)%3D(x%5E2-y%5E2%2C2xy)%24&p=1) you can find some posts about the same function (or even about the same problem). For example: [$f(x,y)=(x^2-y^2,2xy)$ is one to one on the set $A$ consisting of all $(x,y)$ with $x>0$. What is the set $f(A)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/851812) or [Question from Munkres Analysis on Manifolds Inverse Function Theorem Section](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/921965). (The latter is about the third part of the exercise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compute the norm: $$\|f(x,y)\|=\sqrt{(x^2-y^2)^2+4(xy)^2}=\sqrt{x^4-2(xy)^2+y^4+4(xy)^2}=x^2+y^2$$

so you get: $f(x,y)=f(a,b)\implies (x^2-y^2,2xy,x^2+y^2)=(a^2-b^2,2ab,a^2+b^2)$, use the first and last coordinates to show that $(a,b)=(\pm |x|,\pm |y|)$ (add and subtract them), use $A$ to conclude that $a=x$ ($x,a>0$) and use the second coordinate to get $b=y$

Comment: If $x >0, $ how does that force $x = a$? Can't we have $x = -a$ with $a < 0?$ So its not one to one?

Comment: @Hawk Because $f(x,y)=f(a,b)\implies(x,y)=(a,b)$ in the set $A$ with the $x$-coordinate being positive so $x,a>0$

Comment: @TheSimpliFire "$\implies (x,y) = (a,b)$" is what you need to show, you can't assume this. But I think I see where this is going. Since $x >0$ this also forces the $(a,b)$ to be in $x>0$, and hence $a >0$ so the case $-a > 0$ is not considered

Comment: @Hawk That's what I was trying to say

Answer (score 5):

This is simpler in polar coordinates: The map is

$$r(\cos t,\sin t) \to r^2(\cos^2t - \sin^2t, 2\cos t \sin t) = r^2(\cos 2t,\sin 2t).$$

Thus the ray in the right half plane making angle $t$ with the $x$-axis is sent injectively to the ray making angle $2t$ with the $x$-axis. Overalll injectivity follows.

Answer (score 2):

We can prove $f$ is 1-1 by showing there is an explicit inverse function:

$f(x,y) = (x^2-y^2, 2xy) = (s.t)$

$\Rightarrow s^2 + t^2 = x^4 + 2 x^2y^2 + y^4 = (x^2 + y^2)^2$

$\Rightarrow x^2 = \frac{s + \sqrt{s^2 + t^2}}{2}$

There is no ambiguity over the sign of $\sqrt{s^2+t^2}$ here because we know $x^2$ must be $\ge 0$. Since $x > 0$ we have $x = +\sqrt{x^2}$ and then $y = \frac{t}{2x}$.